# AWS Cognito Device Registration impact for existing user

Tags: amazon-cognito

I would like to update parameter `Do you want to remember your user's devices?` from No to Always. However, we are currently having quite a number of user profiles. My question is what the impact if any for existing users?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have conducted quick experiment by toggling the flag between `Always` and `No`, everything seems good without any change for existing user.